# NoClassDefFoundError during Maven Build

Tags: java, maven, bukkit

I'm attempting to make a Bukkit plugin with this tutorial:
http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial

Everything's great, except when I try to build the project with Maven in any way (Clean, Build, Test), it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DevClassPathHelper
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenEmbeddedRuntime.addBundleClasspathEntries(MavenEmbeddedRuntime.java:193)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenEmbeddedRuntime.initClasspath(MavenEmbeddedRuntime.java:127)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenEmbeddedRuntime.createLauncherConfiguration(MavenEmbeddedRuntime.java:107)
at org.eclipse.m2e.internal.launch.MavenRuntimeLaunchSupport.create(MavenRuntimeLaunchSupport.java:119)
at org.eclipse.m2e.internal.launch.MavenLaunchDelegate.launch(MavenLaunchDelegate.java:70)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:883)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DevClassPathHelper cannot be found by org.eclipse.m2e.core_1.4.0.20130601-0317
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
```

My pom.xml is as follows:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.github.learning25</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestPlugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <source>1.7</source>
                  <target>1.7</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
    <repositories>
       <repository>
           <id>bukkit-repo</id>
           <url>http://repo.bukkit.org/content/groups/public/</url>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
           <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
           <version>1.6.4-R2.0</version>
           <type>jar</type>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: which version of Eclipse you are using ?

Comment: Looks an m2e issue to me, try their support. You can start downloading a fresh version of Eclipse, it should contain that plugin by default. Alternatively, you can always run Maven from the command line w/o Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running into the same problem myself.  It appears to be caused by this bug, and is caused an issue with Eclipse Luna and the M2E plugin:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=412436

Assuming you *are* using Luna and have M2E installed, I resolved the problem by uninstalling M2E and reinstalling using the "install new software" route rather than "marketplace".  Couldn't say why, but this seems to have worked for me.

Comment: Having same issue, Re-install M2E with latest version 1.8.2 and it works ! Thanks

Comment: Had the issue with `Neon 3` and reinstall solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue; I tried following and got resolved issue.
I am using Eclipse - Version: 2023-06 (4.28.0) and Maven 3.8.1
Same issue I got -
I did following.
.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven\3.0 -> Maven version was not latest.
At above location - file -"maven-3.0.pom" - in this pom file changed org.apache.maven.plugins value to the same version which is refer in project pom file -
After that got couple of alerts from eclipse to install feature related jars - did that and it worked -
Main reason seems to be different version of maven refer through out eclipse setup and project pom files

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).